# Show that $f(x)+g(x)$ and $f(x)-g(x)$ are not continuous.

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity

Suppose $f(x)$ is continuous at 2, and $g(x)$ is not continuous at 2. Show that $f(x)+g(x)$ and $f(x)-g(x)$ are not continuous at 2.

I need step-by-step solution because I don't know where to start.

Comment: You seem to be missing a "both". One of $f+g$ and $f-g$ may well be continuous at $x=2$.

Answer (score 2):

> Lemma: If $h_1(x), h_2(x)$ are continuous at $x_0$, then $h_1(x) \pm h_2(x)$ is also continuous at $x_0$.

Let $f(x)$ be continuous and $g(x)$ be discontinuous at $x_0 =2$. Suppose, towards a contradiction, that $f(x) + g(x)$ is continuous at $x_0$. Set $h_1(x) = f(x) + g(x), h_2(x) = f(x)$,which are continuous. By the Lemma, $h_1(x)-h_2(x) = g(x)$ must be continuous, a contradiction.